# State is being initialized with [object Object] in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the async function below, I call stationData just to confirm that I'm passing an array of objects into bartData (which is just an empty array). Attached is a response of the array of Objects that I am receiving. However, when trying to use this.state.bartData (to confirm that it does have the array of objects), my return function is returning bartData as undefined. Any ideas?

```
    import React from 'react';

    const bartKey = process.env.REACT_API_BART_API_KEY;

    class StationBaseRoutes extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            station: [],
            stationAbbv: 'ALL',
            destination: '',
            bartData: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getAllStationRoutes();
    }

    async getAllStationRoutes(){
        try{
            setInterval(async () => {
                const response = await fetch(`http://api.bart.gov/api/etd.aspx?cmd=etd&orig=${this.state.stationAbbv}&key=${bartKey}&json=y`);
                const jsonResponse = await response.json();
                const apiData = jsonResponse.root;
                const stationData = apiData.station;
                console.log(stationData);
                this.setState(({
                    isLoading: false,
                    bartData: stationData
                }), () => {
                    console.log(`Callback: ${this.state.bartData}`)
                })
            }, 20000)     
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    getRoutes = () => {
        console.log(`bartData: ${this.bartData}`)
    }

    render(){
        const {station, destination} = this.state;

        return(
          <div>
              <h2>Calling get routes: {this.getRoutes()}</h2>
              <h2>Origin: {station}</h2>
              <h3>Destination: {destination}</h3>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default StationBaseRoutes;
```

Responses: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVVaY.jpg

Comment: Responses link doesn't work.

Comment: @MattCarlotta fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get the Bart API to work in a codesandbox, so I had to mock the API... however, the data is still structured the same.

On that note, the API is working as expected, you just need to `map` over the `objects` in the `this.state.bartData` array and deconstruct the properties you want to show.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/031pn7w680

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { fakeAPI } from "../../api/fakeAPI";

class StationBaseRoutes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      station: [],
      stationAbbv: "ALL",
      destination: "",
      bartData: []
    };

    this.getAllStationRoutes = this.getAllStationRoutes.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllStationRoutes();
  }

  async getAllStationRoutes() {
    try {
      const res = await fakeAPI.get();
      const apiData = res.data.root;
      const stationData = apiData.station;

      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        bartData: stationData
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { bartData, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="app-container">
        {isLoading ? (
          <p className="t-a-c">Loading...</p>
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
            <h1 className="t-a-c">Bart Stations</h1>
            {map(bartData, ({ name, etd }) => (
              <div className="jumbotron station" key={name}>
                <h1>Origin: {name}</h1>
                {map(etd, ({ destination }) => (
                  <li key={destination}>Destination: {destination}</li>
                ))}
              </div>
            ))}
            <pre className="preview">
              <code>{JSON.stringify(bartData, null, 4)}</code>
            </pre>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default StationBaseRoutes;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of bugs here.

First of all, `getRoutes()` is using `this.bartData` instead of `this.state.bartData`

Secondly, all your objects in `console.log` are being converted to strings. You can change it to

```
console.log('bartData:', this.state.bartData);
```

to be able to see the actual data.